# Can I paradoxiacally interpret "there is little room for"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am wondering about the nuance of "there is little room for" in the following context.

> Some photographers might feel like there is little room for creativity in high-volume photography.
> However, many photographers choose to use this niche to create a steady income while simultaneously working on other more creative pursuits.

While I am aware that "there is little room for" basically means "there is almost no room for", in this context, I actually felt that it might paradoxically mean that some photographers (who have no experience in the high-volume photoshoot yet) think they could still be a bit creative, and the latter sentence is denying it saying many rather focus on making money in the niche separting it from crative pursuits.

Am I thinking too much to think like the above? haha.

Comment: No, I don't think you can interpret it that way. It says that high-volume photography doesn't give much opportunity for creativity, but some professionals use it to make money while expressing their creativity in other fields.

Answer (score 2):

There is the word "little" and the phrase "a little", and they make different contrasts. "Little" means "a small amount as opposed to a large amount". For "a small amount as opposed to none", we have "a little". To paraphrase Fowler in *Modern English Usage*, "little" means some but not at all much, and "a little" means not at all much but some. (Fowler was explaining the difference between "few" and "a few", which is similar.)